# Excel Workbook Linked to Another Workbook with a Changing Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to link two workbooks in Excel and have the links remain intact if I change the name of one of the workbooks? I am constantly updating the name of one of the workbooks to reflect it's version number (i.e. I change **`Workbook_v1.xls`** to **`Workbook_v2.xls`** when I make progress on it). Anybody out there know if there are any workarounds to make my links in the unchanged workbook stay intact when I change the name of my other workbook?

Here is my sumif that I am using to get information from another workbook.

```
=SUMIF('[Workbook_v1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$10,$D$1:$D$10,'Sheet3'!$B1:$B10)
```

You can see the problem I have if I change the name to **`Workbook_v2`**, the link is no longer supported. Thank you for any insight you may have!

Comment: [Data - Connections group - Edit Links - Change Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-or-change-source-workbooks-of-external-references-links-ae3e687c-97ae-4d9b-b684-8756a5301253#bmchange_the_source_workbook_for_all_ex)

Comment: Willing to use VBA?

Comment: Yea I can use VBA, is that the only way?

Comment: And thank you @Axel Richter, appreciate the response